# R graphics: output to several file formats

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, lattice, device-driver

In a number of scripts I first develop a graph on screen, and then need to save it as several file formats with particular height/width/resolution.  Using `png()`, `pdf()`, `svg()`, ... to open a device, and then `dev.off()` to close it, I'm forced to put all the device open calls into my script and comment them out & re-run the code one device at a time.

I do know that for ggplot graphics, `ggsave()` makes this easier.
Is there any thing I can do to simplify this for **base-R** and **lattice** graphics?

One example:

```
png(filename="myplot.png", width=6, height=5, res=300, units="in")
# svg(filename="myplot.svg", width=6, height=5)
# pdf(filename="myplot.pdf", width=6, height=5)

op <- par()  # set graphics parameters
plot()       # do the plot
par(op)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

The graphics devices are part of the grDevices package. The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/dev.html) on working with multiple open devices might be worth reading through. From what I understand, a circular array of open devices is stored, but only the current device is active. For that reason, opening all the desired devices and then looping over them with `dev.list()` is likely your best bet.

```
# data for sample plot
x <- 1:5
y <- 5:1

# open devices
svg(filename="myplot.svg", width=6, height=5)
png(filename="myplot.png", width=6, height=5, res=300, units="in")
pdf()

# devices assigned an index that can be used to call them
dev.list()
svg png pdf 
  2   3   4 

# loop through devices, not sure how to do this without calling plot() each time
# only dev.cur turned off and dev.next becomes dev.cur
for(d in dev.list()){plot(x,y); dev.off()} 

# check that graphics device has returned to default null device
dev.cur()
null device 
      1 
dev.list()
NULL

file.exists("myplot.svg")
[1] TRUE
file.exists("myplot.png")
[1] TRUE
file.exists("Rplots.pdf") # default name since none specified in creating pdf device
[1] TRUE
```

There's quite a bit more in the documentation that you can work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the cowplot package to convert your base or lattice graphics into ggplot2 objects that you can then save via `ggsave()`. This is not entirely foolproof but will work for most plots. You'll also need to install the gridGraphics package for this to work. See more [here.](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/mixing_plot_frameworks.html)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> ********************************************************
#> Note: As of version 1.0.0, cowplot does not change the
#>   default ggplot2 theme anymore. To recover the previous
#>   behavior, execute:
#>   theme_set(theme_cowplot())
#> ********************************************************

# define a function that emits the desired plot
p1 <- function() {
  par(
    mar = c(3, 3, 1, 1),
    mgp = c(2, 1, 0)
  )
  boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, xlab = "cyl", ylab = "mpg", data = mtcars)
}

# the plot using base graphics
p1()
```

[image]

```r
# the plot converted into a ggplot2 object
p2 <- ggdraw(p1)
p2
```

[image]

```r
# save in different formats
ggsave("plot.pdf", p2)
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
ggsave("plot.png", p2)
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
ggsave("plot.svg", p2)
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>